# tkinter GUI doesn't work when clicking .pyw

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a piece of code that does two things: writes a .txt file to my current path and runs a module (which I can't see contents of as the files are all .pyc) which ultimately opens a tkinter GUI.

Here is the code:

```
import os.path
from tkinter import messagebox as msg

if not os.path.isfile('FAST Locked.txt'):
    FASTlck = open('FAST Locked.txt', 'w+')
    FASTlck.write('Locked')
    FASTlck.close()

    import pyFiles.FAST

    os.remove('FAST Locked.txt')

else:
    msg.showerror('FAST Locked', 'FAST is open by another user.\n' +\
                  'Please try again later')
    exit()
```

When I run this code from an editor (IDLE or Spyder), it works perfectly. When I double click the .pyw file it only creates the .txt, I do not get the GUI. If I click the .pyw with the .txt file present, I DO get the error message. This makes me think it's something to do with the files inside this FAST module.

I'm running Python 3.7, recently had Anaconda installed on my work machine, previously they just ran Python 3.7 and used IDLE (every other work machine still does this, the code works fine). This makes me wonder if having conda/Spyder installed has messed it up?

Not sure which problem is more likely, and have no idea where to start as I'm relatively new to Python and all this code was written by someone else who's gone.